# Can I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop with 768MB RAM and a Pentium M processor?

Tags: 12.04

My Laptop has 768MB RAM and a Pentium-M 2.00 GHz processor. Can I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my Laptop? Will it slow down?

Comment: Speed is a relative thing. Ubuntu has many flavors and I would suggest you look into something like Lubuntu.

Comment: what about 11.10?

Comment: You could also try other Linux distros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you meet the [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu.

but it wont be fast, I would suggest you try something like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Lastly this is up to you if you feel it's fast enough, try out the system you want with a live usb, that will give a feeling of how fast it will be.